# take text in span data icon selenium vba

Tags: vba, selenium, ms-access, xpath, web-scraping

I would like to take the text "msg-dblcheck" within this code and insert it into an MSaccess table:

```html
<div class="_32uRw">
  <span data-icon="msg-dblcheck" class="">
    <svg id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 15" width="16" height="15">
      <path fill="#92A58C" d="M15.01 3.316l-.478-.372a.365.365 0 0 0-.51.063L8.666 9.879a.32.32 0 0 1-.484.033l-.358-.325a.319.319 0 0 0-.484.032l-.378.483a.418.418 0 0 0 .036.541l1.32 1.266c.143.14.361.125.484-.033l6.272-8.048a.366.366 0 0 0-.064-.512zm-4.1 0l-.478-.372a.365.365 0 0 0-.51.063L4.566 9.879a.32.32 0 0 1-.484.033L1.891 7.769a.366.366 0 0 0-.515.006l-.423.433a.364.364 0 0 0 .006.514l3.258 3.185c.143.14.361.125.484-.033l6.272-8.048a.365.365 0 0 0-.063-.51z"></path>
    </svg>
  </span>
</div>
```

this is my tried code:

```
spnt= bot.findElementByClassName("_32uRw").text
```

unfortunately I insert field "-1".
Where am I wrong? In selecting the field? Should I search with xpath? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
.FindElementByCss("._32uRw span").Attribute("data-icon")
```

I don't know how many class names you have before this one though. The above will match on the first by that class name with a following span.

You can do `FindElementsByCSS`,  and index into the returned `webElements` collection e.g. `.FindElementsByCss("._32uRw span")(1).Attribute("data-icon")`

With the above you don't need `.Text` on the end. This would return `msg-dblcheck`.

For the last element with this attribute:

```
Dim numElements As Long, lastElement As WebElement
numElements = bot.FindElementsByCss("[data-icon='msg-dblcheck']").Count
Set lastElement = bot.FindElementsByCss("[data-icon='msg-dblcheck']")(numElements-1)
```

To include the class name of the element before change the text `[data-icon='msg-dblcheck']` to  `._32uRw [data-icon='msg-dblcheck']` .

Comment: I managed to solve my problem with the first part of the answer you gave me. Unfortunately when I insert that count to get the last element the function stops responding. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, I checked with other tests and unfortunately I have not solved. I'll point out an error that I'll see in a moment

Comment: error run time ..... index not included in the interval. required non-negative value and less than the size of the set. parameter name: index

Comment: on Set lastElement = bot.FindElementsByCss("[data-icon='msg-dblcheck']")(numElements)Set lastElement = bot.FindElementsByCss("[data-icon='msg-dblcheck']")(numElements)   I noticed that the count works perfectly (the number found is highlighted in the debug)

Comment: Odd. Try Set lastElement = bot.FindElementsByCss("[data-icon='msg-dblcheck']")(numElements-1) just as an experiment.

Comment: Now it seems to go on, I do some tests and I'll let you know if it gets the right data. Why then -1?

Comment: I will admit to being confused as with selenium webElements collection it should be 1 based i.e. start at one. Meaning that .Count should be the last element. -1 is an adjustment assuming a 0 based indexing which is what you get with IHTMLCollections

Comment: Thanks, in this way I solved the problem. in debt with you QHarr! :)